# How to plot individual elements of a pandas dataframe using Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

Is there a way to extract the individual elements in a variable created using Pandas? I loaded 3 columns [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulkJs.gif)of data into a dataframe, called X1, using the function SelectData. Next, I want to plot the selected data from X1, but plot them individually. The reason I'm doing this is to run Random Forest to make a prediction. In the attached plot, I selected two columns of data, which are saved into the variable X1. I can plot X1, but both columns are on the same track. I would like to be able to plot them individually.

The code is shown below:

## Function to select the data

```
def SelectData(self):
    global X1
    global selected_columns
    selected_columns = self.lb_logs.curselection()
    sel_values = []
    listLogs2 = list(df.columns.values)
    print(listLogs2)
    for i in selected_columns:
        sel_values.append(listLogs2[i])
    print(selected_columns)
    print(sel_values)
    X1 = df[sel_values]
```

## Function to plot the data

```
def PlotData_canvas(self):

    if df.empty == True:
        m_box.showerror('Error', 'No data has been imported.')
    else:
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(8,8))
        self.fig.suptitle('Input Logs Depth Plot', fontsize=24)
        ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(131)
        ax1.plot(X1, df2['Depth'], color = 'g', linewidth=1)
        ax1.set_xlabel('X1')
        ax1.set_ylabel('Depth (m)')
        ax1.invert_yaxis()

        ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(132)
        ax2.plot(X1, df2['Depth'], color = 'r', linewidth=1)
        ax2.set_xlabel('Vs (m/s)')
        ax2.invert_yaxis()

        ax3 = self.fig.add_subplot(133)
        ax3.plot(y1, df2['Depth'], color = 'b', linewidth=1)
        ax3.set_xlabel('Target Log')
        ax3.invert_yaxis() 

        canvas_main = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.MainTab)
        canvas_main.draw()
        canvas_main.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
```